# Change view modes with fade-in and fade-out (and set a cookie)

Tags: jquery, cookies, fadein, fadeout, setcookie

I need to give users the option to choose view modes between `List-view`, `Grid-view`, and `Full-view`. The basic structure is simple, something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">List Toggle</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Grid Toggle</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Full Toggle</a></li> 
</ul>

<div id="wrap">
<div id="list-view">
    <div class="line">lorem line</div>
    <div class="line">lorem line</div>
    <div class="line">lorem line</div>
</div>

<div id="grid-view">
    <div class="box">lorem box</div>
    <div class="box">lorem box</div>
    <div class="box">lorem box</div>
</div>

<div id="full-view">
    <div class="full">full lorem</div>
    <div class="full">full lorem</div>
    <div class="full">full lorem</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a `jsfiddle` I started with `list-view` set as visible and others hidden:

http://jsfiddle.net/eTb5C/13/

Here is one I was thinking of implementing, but need it for 3 options..
http://jsfiddle.net/mgNQy/2/

Basically, if you click on a view mode, the current view mode will fade out and the selected view mode will fade in.

I would also like to add a cookie to remember the user's preference if possible, but I don't know how to do that. I am pretty new to jQuery hopefully my questions aren't too basic.

Comment: So is your question "How do I use a cookie for a user's preferences?", or "Can somebody please write the jQuery code from scratch?" What have you tried so far? Have you looked at `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`?

Comment: I did use something like this, but you can only alternate 2 view modes...http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/TX3G2/

I would like the cookie preferences option, but maybe that should be a different question sorry.

Comment: Here is another: http://jsfiddle.net/mgNQy/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acutally there is nothing special, you have only three tabs ( list, grid, full ). 
First, i recommend to you to follow the mark-up below :

```
   <ul class="tabs js-view-mode">
      <li><a href="#list">List</a></li>
      <li><a href="#grid">Grid</a></li>
      <li><a href="#full">Full</a></li>
    </ul>

    <section id="viewMode">
      <div id="list">here is list mode content</div>
      <div id="grid">here is grid mode content</div>
      <div id="full">here is full mode content</div>
    </section>
```

As you can see, on tabs, inside `<a href="">` class i put the id's for what we want to show. This is safe and easy because the script will not confuse what he has to show.

Also in html you must load jquery library and jquery-cookie ( you can avoid loading this plugin following the documentation for [javascript-cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) ). Better load them before `</body>` tag to get a faster loading time for page.

The jQuery code for what you want looks like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var wrap = $('#viewMode'),
      viewMode = $.cookie( 'view-mode' );
  wrap.children().hide();

  $('.js-view-mode').on( 'click', 'a',function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $(this),
        type = t.attr('href');

    $(type).fadeIn()
      .siblings().fadeOut();

    viewMode = $.cookie( 'view-mode', type );

  });

  if ( viewMode ) {
    $('.js-view-mode a[href='+ viewMode +']').trigger('click');
  } else {
    $('.js-view-mode li:first a').trigger( 'click' );
  }

});
```

You can see a live test [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9ae3T/)

**Edit :** [JS Fiddle v2](http://fiddle.jshell.net/stefanz/9ae3T/21/) ( add active clas + delay fadeIn/Out + return on clicking active item )

Comment: Thanks Stefanz! That looks great and is very simple. Is there a reason that when you switch view modes, the content jumps up instead of smoothly fading in and out?

Comment: Yes. The problem is about css. You have to put #viewMode position:relative; and its children position:absolute;

Btw, please make it the correct answer if you think so

Comment: Thanks, I did. The problem is that my site is responsive/fluid and adding a position:relative and absolute will throw it off. Is it possible to do it another way?

Comment: For moment i have only this idea :
Replace $(type).fadeIn().siblings().fadeOut()
with        
 wrap.children().fadeOut();
 $(type).delay(500).fadeIn();

Anyway, the delay parameter depends by the length of your content. Any value below 500 will give you some problems. Just try it and see what is happening.

Comment: Not sure if you will get this comment Stefanz, but I was trying to make it so if you click an anchor for the active view mode, nothing will happen. Now, it will fade out and back in..

Comment: Thank you for getting back with me! Only one problem.. I updated the original code to add a height to the content so when transitioning, it wouldn't collapse. Could you add that script to the new code? I can't seem to do it correctly. Here it is...
http://fiddle.jshell.net/9ae3T/23/